# Return list of nums based on num condition

Tags: python, matlab

I want to get 1 if the num in list is larger than 0.5, and 0 else.

For example, a is a list

Matlab:

```
b = (a > 0.5)
```

Python:

```
b = [1 if x > 0.5 else 0 for x in a]
b = [int(x > 0.5) for x in a]
```

I'd like to know if there is a shorter expression coded in Python?

Comment: `a` is a matrix here?

Comment: Yes, if you use `numpy`. It's as simple as the matlab equivalent.

Comment: Oh, I got you. Thanks! @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: `map(lambda x:int(x>.5) , x)` this will do

Comment: Why do you think what you have currently is not short enough? Python code should be readable, it is not a golfing language

Comment: my bad. didn't get his question at first. `b = [int(x > 0.5) for x in a]` is already short enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case `a` is a matrix, you better use a **numpy** array. This is basically the matlab counterpart in Python:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([0.35,0.76,0.22,0.10])
>>> a > 0.5
array([False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> (a > 0.5).astype(int)
array([0, 1, 0, 0])
```

So `a > 0.5` constructs an array with the same dimensions as the original one with booleans that store `True` in case the number if greater than `0.5`, and `False` otherwise.

By using `.astype(int)` you can convert it to another type (than a boolean), for instance an `int`.

Numpy can work with arrays with arbitrary dimensions, and furthermore the calls are done by a dedicated package outside Python, making it better performance-wise.